# Container View inside split view controller on iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am using xcode 6.1 (latest version), running on iPad and my application is using an `UISplitViewContoller`.
The master and the detail are both embedding a `UINavigationController` (as advised by Apple in their documents). My problem is related to the master side of `UISplitViewContoller`.
[image: UISplitVewController architecture with UINavigationController and UISegmentControl]

The master has a `UISegmentControl` that allows the user to select  between 3 types of view “current”, “shot” and “session” that change the **master** view. I have implemented this by embedding a container view in the master (and have set the correct constraints to size it to the complete master view size). The container view a standard object that can be dragged out in storyboard:

[image: Container view can be dragged from storyboard]

I have created a class `HixFieldViewControllerMaster` that represents the master (assigned the class in the storyboard) and connected the segment control and container in storyboard:

[image: HixFieldViewControllerMaster class connected in storyboard]

The `HixFieldViewControllerMaster` is derived from my class `HixViewControllerContainer` (so I can reuse the container view behaviour for other classes) that includes the function `(void)loadViewWithClass:(Class) myClass`

This function takes care of loading the actual view controller in the container view

```
@interface HixViewControllerContainer ()
@property (weak, nonatomic)   UIView  *  containerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * currentStoryBoardID;
@end

@implementation HixViewControllerContainer


#pragma mark - helper functions


-(void)loadViewWithClass:(Class)myClass
{
 //if the class does not implement the required function assert (in debug)
 if(![myClass respondsToSelector:@selector(instantiateFromStoryboard:)])
  {
  HixALog(@"%@ does not implement instantiateFromStoryboard",myClass);
  return;
  }
 //if already loaded do nothing...
 if([self.containerView class] == myClass) return;
 //Remove the current Detail View Controller showed
 if(self.currentContainerViewController)
  {
  [self.currentContainerViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  [self.currentContainerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  [self.currentContainerViewController removeFromParentViewController];
  }
 //create new vc
 UIViewController * newVC=[myClass instantiateFromStoryboard:self.storyboard];
 //set correct auto resize behaviour
 newVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
 //Add the detail controller as child of the container
 [self addChildViewController:newVC];
 //define the detail controller's view size
 newVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
 //add the Detail controller's view to the Container's detail view and save a reference to the detail View Controller
 [self.containerView addSubview:newVC.view];
 UIView *myView=newVC.view;
 //set correct constraits so resizing is ok
 [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[myView]-0-|"
                                     options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                     metrics:nil
                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];

 [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[myView]-0-|"
                                     options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                     metrics:nil
                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];
 //store new vc as the current one
 self.currentContainerViewController = newVC;
 //complete the add flow calling the function didMoveToParentViewController
 [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This was working fine on iOS 7.x but is behaving erratically on iOS8; when user select different views using the segment control, sometimes the master windows goes blank, sometimes it shows the view but its not linked to the code (it just displays the stuff drawn in storyboard but no underlying code is executed).

I am confident that the `instantiateFromStoryBoard` logic is working correctly (I am not getting any log from the HixALog function that it failed). It is my believe that I am probably doing something wrong with the `willMoveToParentViewController`, `removeFromSuperview`… or other viewcontroller housekeeping…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody reading this, I never found a solution for this.
In the end, I removed the segment control (top of screen) and worked with a tab control (bottom of the screen).